# value getDay is not a function Typescript Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I found a similar question but it did not answer the issue I am facing.

I am trying to parse a date into a string. Here is my implementation.

```
export class DataFormater {

    formatDDMMMYYY(date: Date): string {
        return date.getDay().toString() + '/' + date.getMonth().toString() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString();
    }

}
```

but I get an error saying `date.getDay() is not a function`? When I look at the doc's it is a number, hence the `.toString()`. Has anyone encountered this or found a better way to implement a way to parse a date to a string to a desired output.

-------------- Full implementation ----------

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                           name="dp" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" (keyup)="setFilter()">
```

in component

```
toDate: Date;
fromDate: Date;

constructor(private dateFormater: DataFormater) {
    this.toDate = new Date();
    this.fromDate = new Date();
}

setFilter() {    
        if (this.toDate != null) {
            console.log(this.toDate + " in toDate...");
            this.filter.toDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(this.toDate);
        }
        if (this.fromDate != null) {
            this.filter.fromDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(this.fromDate);
        }
        this.filterEmitter.emit(this.filter);
    }
```

DateFormater

```
export class DataFormater {

    constructor(){
        console.log(this.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date))
    }

    formatDDMMMYYY(date: Date): string {
        date = new Date(date);
        return date.getDay().toString() + '/' + date.getMonth().toString() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us date value!

Answer (score 2):

You must be passing the date to the function in incorrect format.

Try like this:

```
constructor(){
  console.log(this.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date))
}

formatDDMMMYYY(date: Date): string {
   return date.getDate().toString() + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString();
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bpvh2q?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Note: Since you want to convert id to DD/MM/YYYY, use `date.getDate()` instead of `date.getDay()`.
`date.getDay()` gives the week day. 5 for Friday ( Sunday means 0)

Comment: Can you share stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaSharma, it's not necesary "toString()". JavaScript "+" convert to string if there're a string in the "sum". BTW, I like `('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ('0' + (date.getMonth()+1).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear()`

Comment: Yeah... toString isn't required. Just copied from his question :)

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. Thank you very much for your effort!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The `date object` on which you are calling `getDate()` function might not be a `valid date object`. So you might be getting the error.

Once send a **valid date object** and check that function,

Eg:

`this.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date());`

**Updated Answer, as per the question:**

Change this part, `new Date(this.fromDate)`

`this.filter.fromDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date(this.fromDate));`

```
setFilter() {    
        if (this.toDate != null) {
            console.log(this.toDate + " in toDate...");
            this.filter.toDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(this.toDate);
        }
        if (this.fromDate != null) {
            this.filter.fromDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date(this.fromDate));
        }
        this.filterEmitter.emit(this.filter);
    }
```

DateFormater

```
export class DataFormater {

    constructor(){
        console.log(this.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date))
    }

    formatDDMMMYYY(date: Date): string {
        return date.getDate().toString() + '/' + date.getMonth().toString() + '/' + date.getFullYear().toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Drew, Please check the updated answer as per your question.

Comment: Please, check your code, is getDate(), not getDay() -getDay return day of week-

Comment: yes because he needed the Day number, it is `getDay()` as per his question

Comment: Sravan, really not, getDay return 0 if sunday, 1 if Monday..., getDate return the day of the month

Comment: I figured out what the issue was. Thank you very much for your effort!!!!

Comment: yes also, as @Eliseo said, you should change `getDay()` to `getDate()` as `getDate()` is what returns the exact date. Thumbs up Eliseo, I got your point.

Comment: also, @Drew1208, I updated my answer as per the above change, Ok pease check it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using `ngbDatepicker` it is not native typescript date. Here is the solution.

```
import {NgbDate} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

toDate: NgbDate;
fromDate: NgbDate;
```

parse the date

```
    if (this.fromDate != null) {
        this.filter.fromDate = this.dateFormater.formatDDMMMYYY(this.fromDate);
    }
```

and now the method

```
import {NgbDate} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class DataFormater {

    formatDDMMMYYY(date: NgbDate): string {
        return date.day + '/' + date.month + '/' + date.year;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert string and all. You just pass the date to the function:

Try this:

```
 constructor() {
    console.log(this.formatDDMMMYYY(new Date()));
  }

  formatDDMMMYYY(date: Date): string {
    return moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
```

[**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-y2r4x7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)